# Wait for HTTP request to complete in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I have a scenario where my rails controller action has to make a API request to a backend business logic server which does a lot of computations and returns me the result.

I'm thinking to show a loading page to the user and make the call asynchronous using Faye or any other option and redirect the user when the call is complete..

But even if I make the call asynchronous, the HTTP request needs to wait for the server to return the data after process, which would take around 20 seconds.

I would like to know what is the best way to make such calls in rails.?

Answer (score 2):

I had faced a similar situation, below is the route that I took:

1. When the controller action is triggered
   a. I fired off a 'async' request to the API using a worker(I used sidekiq)
   b. Loaded a 'AJAX' spinner gif on top of a modal
2. The worker handling the API request runs on another thread which is synchronous and waits for the result from the API
3. When the processing is done, the worker fires off notification via 'Faye' which removes the modal and populates the data.

Comment: So basically, you are saying to queue the processes. But queueing has a delay, can't we just make the process start immediately but run in the background.? I understand that would depend on the process threads. Just wondering if there are better ways., cause, I can't keep user waiting when they are multiple requests.

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura you can use something like sidekiq and give highest priority to the queue in which you are doing those computations. Also, you can change the poll interval of sidekiq(the time between each queue checks for new jobs in redis) so that your job starts almost immediately.

Comment: Oki. But another doubt is, the other server which I have to call to get the data processed might take upto 20 Seconds or more to respond. Will the HTTP request in the background worker be alive that long.? Would that cause any problems in the app that I should be aware of..?

Comment: How are you sending the request? Are you using the in-built 'Net::HTTP' method to request and wait for response? If this is the way, from what i know, the thread will wait for a response before going any further. A problem, which is quite trivial if handled correctly, is what are you pushing via faye? What if you are repopulating a table and user is not on that page?

Answer (score 0):

Return an HTTP response with status `202 Accepted`(for the request that need to take long to process) and start making AJAX requests(to a URL, e.g /jobs/1) to check the status of the background job. Once your job has finished, update it's status so that your Javascript(AJAX) can handle the result of that background job.